When is the category of fractions of a topos a topos?
Given a topos $\mathcal{E}$ and a class of morphisms $Q$ in $\mathcal{E}$, when is the category of fractions $\mathcal{E}[Q^{-1}]$ also a topos?
In order for $\mathcal{E}[Q^{-1}]$ to have a "nice" description, $Q$ needs to be either a left or a right "Ore" class. For a left "Ore" class (where $\mathcal{E}[Q^{-1}]$ is constructed using "left fractions" $q^{-1}f$), one would need $Q$ to satisfy the following conditions:

The class $Q$ contains all identities and is closed under composition.
(Left Ore condition) Given any $q:A \to B \in Q$ and any $f:A \to C$, there exist $g:B \to D$ and $r:C \to D \in Q$ for which $g \circ q=r \circ f$.
(Left reversibility) Given any $f,g:A \to B$ for which $f \circ q=g \circ q$ for some $q:C \to A \in Q$, there is also some $r:B \to D \in Q$ for which $r \circ f=r \circ g$.

Dually, for a right "Ore" class (where $\mathcal{E}[Q^{-1}]$ is constructed using "right fractions" $fq^{-1}$), one would need $Q$ to satisfy the following conditions:

The class $Q$ contains all identities and is closed under composition.
(Right Ore condition) Given any $q:A \to C \in Q$ and any $f:B \to C$, there exist $g:D \to A$ and $r:D \to B \in Q$ for which $q \circ g=f \circ r$.
(Right reversibility) Given any $f,g:A \to B$ for which $q \circ f=q \circ g$ for some $q:B \to C \in Q$, there is also some $r:D \to A \in Q$ for which $f \circ r=g \circ r$.

It seems that there are at least three known cases for which $\mathcal{E}[Q^{-1}]$ is a topos. The first case is when $Q$ is the class of morphisms inverted by the "sheafification" functor with respect to some subtopos of $\mathcal{E}$. In this case, $\mathcal{E}[Q^{-1}]$ is equivalent to that subtopos. The class of morphisms inverted by any reflection functor (or idempotent monad) is always a left "Ore" class. In the case of a finite-limit-preserving reflection functor (e.g., sheafification in any subtopos), the class of morphisms inverted by that functor is also a right "Ore" class.
The second case is when one has a connected geometric morphism, where a coreflective subcategory of a topos is closed under finite limits. In this case, the coreflective subcategory is equivalent to the category of fractions with respect to the class of morphisms inverted by the coreflection functor. The class of morphisms inverted by any coreflection functor (or idempotent comonad) is always a right "Ore" class.
Finally, the third case (probably less well-known than either of the first two) is involved in the construction of a "filter quotient topos" $\mathcal{E}/F$, where $F$ is a filter of subterminal objects of $\mathcal{E}$. In this case, $Q$ is the class of morphisms $f$ for which $f \times 1_U$ is an isomorphism for some $U \in F$ (which is both a left and a right "Ore" class), and the "filter quotient topos" $\mathcal{E}/F$ is then just the category of fractions $\mathcal{E}[Q^{-1}]$. This case has the property that the "localization" functor $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{E}/F=\mathcal{E}[Q^{-1}]$ is logical.
